# SQL How to order by date after a convertion to char?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-order-by, distinct, sql-server-2019

I have a datetime column from which I want to show the dates with format "dd/mm/yyyy"

I tried with

```sql
Select distinct CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [DateAndTime], 103) as [DateAndTime]
from dbo.Prod
order by dbo.Prod.[DateAndTime]
```

but it gives me the error:

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified

If i exclude the last line it gives me a result like this

```
DateAndTime
03/03/2023
16/02/2023
17/02/2023
21/02/2023
```

What can I do to have this result ordered by the original column date format?

Comment: Why are you converting the date and time value to a `varchar` in the first place?

Comment: Also, as an FYI, [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns.

Comment: I'm converting it into varchar because i couldn't find another way to have the result date with the format "dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: The format the date is presented in is a job for your presentation layer, not the SQL layer, @dNaver .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group by instead of DISTINCT to do it:

```sql
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [DateAndTime], 103) as [DateAndTime]
from dbo.Prod
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [DateAndTime], 103), CAST(DateAndTime AS DATE)
order by CAST(DateAndTime AS DATE)
```

As other say though, this is usually better to do on frontend side of things

Answer (score 0):

You need to order by the column name in the `SELECT`, rather than a column from one of the tables, as once you have `DISTINCT` you effectively have a `GROUP BY` on all columns. So you need to drop the table reference in the `ORDER BY`.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), p.DateAndTime, 103) as DateAndTime
FROM dbo.Prod p
ORDER BY
  DateAndTime;
```

Note however that this is inefficient, because you are not able to use indexes. Furthermore, `DISTINCT` is usually a code-smell, as it often indicates poor data.

You can group by a conversion to `date` instead

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  CONVERT(date, p.DateAndTime) as DateAndTime
FROM dbo.Prod p
ORDER BY
  DateAndTime;
```

Or if you use `GROUP BY` then you can place it in a `CROSS APPLY` to avoid having to specify it multiple times.

```sql
SELECT
  v.DateAndTime  
FROM dbo.Prod p
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CONVERT(date, p.DateAndTime) as DateAndTime
) v
GROUP BY
  v.DateAndTime
ORDER BY
  v.DateAndTime;
```